# How to trigger Eslints automated fix in SAP Web IDE?

Tags: sap-web-ide

There are some errors which ESLint can fix automatically [as described on their webpage](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#fix) (command-line, AtomText, etc.)

How to do this in the SAP Web IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

currently Web IDE not support automatic fixing of code for ESLint warnings and errors so you will need to do it manually by fixing the line of code. Soon as you will fix it according to ESLint comment the error will not be there anymore

**Update - how to change new line mode**

Changing new line mode can be done from Web IDE user settings 
in order to access user settings you need to click on the settings icon which located on Web IDE right side pane and then select **Code Editor** and under code editor your will see **New Line Mode**

[image: new line image]

Comment: So how to change the EOL encoding? (CRLF vs LF) Not possible in WebIDE?

Comment: i will update the answer and show how it can be done